# How to use two variadic template arguments in one constructor to bind two functions?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to construct an object passing two functions with a variadic number of arguments:

```
class PhaseSetControlProperty : public ControlProperty {

  public:
    template<typename FuncKicked, typename... ArgsKicked, typename FuncActivated, typename... ArgsActivated>
    PhaseSetControlProperty(const std::vector<std::string> &kickedPhaseNames, const std::vector<std::string> &activatedPhaseNames, FuncKicked funcKicked, ArgsKicked ...argsKicked, FuncActivated funcActivated, ArgsActivated... argsActivated): ControlProperty("PhaseSetControl")
    {
    getModel()->addProperty(new StringListProperty("kickedPhaseNames", kickedPhaseNames));
    getModel()->addProperty(new StringListProperty("activePhaseNames", activatedPhaseNames));

    getModel()->addProperty(new StringListProperty("activated", activatedPhaseNames, funcActivated, argsActivated...));
    getModel()->addProperty(new StringListProperty("kicked", kickedPhaseNames, funcKicked, argsKicked...));
    }
};
```

The instantiation looks like this:

```
model->addProperty(new PhaseSetControlProperty(kickedphasenames, activephasenames, &BDlines::kickedPhasesFunctionCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1, &BDlines::activePhasesFunctionCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

this and std::placeholders::_1 are the variadic argments.

The solution before looked like this:

```
kicked_property = new FunctionProperty("kicked", &BDlines::kickedPhasesFunctionCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1);
  activated_property = new FunctionProperty("activated", &BDlines::activePhasesFunctionCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

How does C++ know which arguments belong to which template parameters? How can this be achieved in a simple way?

My current solution is to use two additional functions which add the property "activated" and then the property "kicked", basically like the old version but I want to use only one single call.

Comment: Please break lines so that the important part of your question isn't hidden behind a scrollbar.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `std::tuple<>` to collect the arguments - e.g..

```
template <typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
void foo(const tuple<Args1...>& t1, const tuple<Args2...>& t2) {
    cout << tuple_size<tuple<Args1...>>::value << ' ' << tuple_size<tuple<Args2...>>::value << endl;
}
```

Now propagate the tuple on to the constructor...

Answer (score 0):

> How does C++ know which arguments belong to which template parameters?

It doesn't. This is why template parameter packs are only deducible if they are the last argument.

> How can this be achieved in a simple way?

If each set of arguments is only used to construct a property, you could just take a parameter pack of properties:

```
model->addProperty(new PhaseSetControlProperty(kickedphasenames, activephasenames,
    new StringListProperty (&BDlines::kickedPhasesFunctionCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1),
    new StringListProperty (&BDlines::activePhasesFunctionCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1)));
```

The has the added benefit of also supporting other kinds and numbers of propertied.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question completely, but could you pass functors as template arguments instead of passing function and arguments separately? So your code could look like:

```
template<typename FuncKickedFunctor, typename FuncActivatedFunctor>
    PhaseSetControlProperty(const std::vector<std::string> &kickedPhaseNames, const std::vector<std::string> &activatedPhaseNames, FuncKickedFunctor funcKickedFunctor, FuncActivatedFunctor funcActivatedFunctor): ControlProperty("PhaseSetControl")
    {
    getModel()->addProperty(new StringListProperty("kickedPhaseNames", kickedPhaseNames));
    getModel()->addProperty(new StringListProperty("activePhaseNames", activatedPhaseNames));

    getModel()->addProperty(new StringListProperty("activated", activatedPhaseNames, funcActivatedFunctor));
    getModel()->addProperty(new StringListProperty("kicked", kickedPhaseNames, funcKickedFunctor));
    }
```